# Decompose a polynomial into factors

Tags: polynomials

**Help me factor these polynomials**

- $(x+\sqrt{2})^2$ - 8
- 14a - 49$a^2$ + 100$b^2$ - 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, use $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, so: $$(x+\sqrt{2})^2-8=(x+\sqrt2+2\sqrt2)(x+\sqrt2-2\sqrt2)=(x+3\sqrt2)(x-\sqrt2)$$
For the second case pick a $a$ and use the same rule as the previous answer, so: $$14a(2-7a)+(10b+1)(10b-1)$$ or $$(10b)^2-(7a-1)^2=(10b-7a+1)(10b+7a-1)$$

Comment: The second is more like $(10b)^2-(7a-1)^2$.

Comment: This was meant to then apply the difference-of-squares formula.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Corrected.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x + 3 \sqrt{2})(x - \sqrt{2})$$

$$7 a (2 - 7a) + (10 b + 1)(10 b - 1)$$

Comment: So perhaps an upvote is in order?

Comment: Sure it is due!